# Regular Expression to match outer brackets but ignoring comment lines with brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match outer brackets but ignoring brackets from comment lines inside the outer brackets.

Example string:

```
(
this is an example;
// this is a comment line with an '(' in it and should be ignored
this is (another) line;
)
```

My current regex:

```
\(((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))\)
```

this is, what i get:

```
(' in it and should be ignored
this is (another) line;
)
```

but i need this:

```
this is an example;
// this is a commentline with an '(' in it and should be ignored
this is (another) line;
```

Comment: Can you not check if the string starts with a bracket? It couldn't match a bracket of a line for say a comment that way.

Comment: Why use regex when the opening and closing bracket is a single character in new line?

Comment: this is just an example. The brackets can be in the same line, too.

Comment: I think you were looking for [`\((?>\n//.*|[^()]|\((?<c>)|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c\(\(%3f%3e%5cn%2f%2f.*%7c%5b%5e\(\)%5d%7c%5c\(\(%3f%3cc%3e\)%7c%5c\)\(%3f%3c-c%3e\)\)*\(%3f\(c\)\(%3f!\)\)%5c\)&i=\(%0d%0athis+is+an+example%3b%0d%0a%2f%2f+this+is+a+comment+line+with+an+%27\(%27+in+it+and+should+be+ignored%0d%0athis+is+\(another\)+line%3b%0d%0a\))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the ways to do this.

- Using `(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xS5tJ0/4) which uses `look around` assertions.
- Using `\((.*?)\)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xS5tJ0/3) which uses captured group. Capture `\1`.

**Note:** Use `DOTOALL` flag `s` to allow `.` matching newlines.

[Fixed your demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH2lZ1/2) using `lazy` quantifier `?`.

---

The above regex would work in many cases. After a lot of other specifications by the OP here is the final demo.

<kbd>**[Final Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH2lZ1/6)**</kbd>

Comment: this doesn't work for me.
See [link](https://regex101.com/r/uH2lZ1/1)

I need a match for every outer brackets. If you know, what i mean?

Comment: @Sheik: Let me check. Check the updated answer. I have included your demo in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add more brackets. sometimes i've more inner brackets.
[link](https://regex101.com/r/uH2lZ1/3)
This was the reason for my balancing groups.

Comment: @Sheik: Are your parenthesis `(` and `)` always in newline ?

Comment: No, the brackets can be anywhere.

Comment: @Sheik: Could you please give all kinds of examples ? Because I just fixed the regex to match your new requirements. [Regex as per question modification](https://regex101.com/r/uH2lZ1/4).

Comment: @Sheik: How's this modification in [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uH2lZ1/6) ? Is it sufficient ?

Comment: @Sheik - Either you're looking for balanced text or not. This is not the approach for balanced text, even though it might look like it.

Comment: @sln: Would you like to point out what's wrong with this regex or approach ?

Comment: @noob - Does not do balanced text. What else do you need?

Comment: Doesn't look to me that OP was looking for balanced text.

Comment: @noob - It's possible you missed the part where he said outer paren's, or showed a regex sample using (?<push-pop>) balanced groups, or where one of his comments was the paren's can be anywhere. Beyond that, your regex doesn't look for any outer open close paren's. There is no _outer_ in your context, just a fixed pseudo-anchored location. Why he marked an answer he is not going to use is a little strange. Obviously he is trying to do some structured language parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\((([^)]+)|(\/\/[^\n]+\n))\)
```

Comment: It would improve your answer if you explained how what you're proposing solves the problem.